# Does lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to non-type lvalue template argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, implicit-conversion

```
struct S{
   constexpr S() {};
};
template <auto x> void f();

int main() {

    S s{};
    f<s>();
}
```

First off, per [[temp.arg.nontype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.nontype#1)

> If the type T of a template-parameter (13.2) contains a placeholder
> type (9.2.9.6) or a placeholder for a deduced class type (9.2.9.7),
> the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable x in
> the invented declaration
>
> ```
> T x = template-argument;
> ```
>
> If a deduced parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter
> declaration (13.2), the program is ill-formed.

Our template parameter contains a placeholder type `auto`, so the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration `auto x = s;` In this case, the type of the parameter is `S`, and `S` is a permitted type for the parameter declaration because `S` is a structural literal type.

Second, [per [temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.arg.nontype#2)

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
> converted constant expression (7.7) of the type of the
> template-parameter.

This means the template-argument `s` shall be a converted constant expression. So per [[expr.const]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#10):

> A converted constant expression of type `T` is an expression, implicitly
> converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant
> expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> - [..]
> - (10.2) — lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (7.3.2)
> - [..]

I'm not sure whether or not the lvalue `s` is converted to prvalue before any implicit conversions are applied to it. Note the definition of converted constant expression in C++14 is relatively changed. [N4140 §5.19 [expr.const]/3:](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const#3) (emphasis mine)

> A converted constant expression of type `T` is an expression, implicitly
> converted to a **prvalue** of type `T`, where the converted expression is a
> core constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains
> only [..]

So per C++14, It's guaranteed that the converted expression is converted to a prvalue before any implicit conversion is applied to it.

I'm not so sure whether or not an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to template-argument `s`. In other words, I'm not sure that the lvalue `s` is converted to a prvalue.

So in general, if I passed an lvalue as a template argument for a non-type template parameter, does an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to that lvalue?

And aside from that, Is the object `s` [*constant-initialized*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#2)?

Comment: "I'm not sure whether an implicit conversion is applied to `s`." Why not? The text clearly demands that the converted constant expression be "implicitly converted to type `T`".

Comment: @BrianBi - Thanks for the catch. I will edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of [expr.const]/10 is that whenever an expression appears in a context that requires a "converted constant expression of type `T`", that expression is "implicitly converted to type `T`" and the additional restrictions in [expr.const]/10 shall apply.

So `s` is not "converted to a prvalue before any implicit conversions are applied to it". Rather, `s` is implicitly converted to type `S`, and this implicit conversion might involve some standard and/or user-defined conversions, such as an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. To know whether or not it does, we would have to look at the rules for implicit conversions, which are in [conv.general]. In particular [[conv.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#6) states that

> The effect of any implicit conversion is the same as performing the corresponding declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type ([dcl.ref]), an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.
> The expression *E* is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

I believe the wording here is a relic of older standard editions. What it should say (in modern language) is that when `T` is a non-reference type, an implicit conversion of *E* to `T` yields a prvalue that initializes its result object (call it `t`) as if by `T t = E;`.

So we consider `S t = s;` What does this initialization do? It calls the copy constructor of `S` to initialize `t`; [[dcl.init.general]/16.6.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#16.6.2.1). There is no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in this scenario. (Lvalue-to-rvalue conversions on class types are rare, but do occur in some places in the language, e.g., [[expr.call]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.call#12), [[expr.cond]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.cond#7). If an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion were performed on `s`, it would also call the copy constructor; [[conv.lval]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.lval#3.2). But in this particular case, the rules of the language do not require an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.)

Consequently, the result of using `s` as a template argument for a template parameter of type `S` is that a prvalue is generated that initializes its result object by calling the copy constructor with `s` as the argument. (This particular copy constructor is implicitly defined to not do anything, since there are no subobjects to copy.)

This answers your question regarding whether an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied. (You might be wondering what actually happens to the prvalue and whether the copy constructor actually gets called, but that's a separate topic that I don't want to get into right now, because it would make this answer too long.)

As for whether `s` is constant-initialized, yes it is. It satisfies (2.1) (since it has an initializer) and (2.2) since the full-expression of its initialization is a constant expression (there is nothing to stop it from being a constant expression, since it does nothing other than calling the `constexpr` default constructor, which itself does nothing). I'm not sure how this is relevant to your other question, though.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I have a problem understanding why you said _" It satisfies .. (2.2) since the full-expression of its initialization is a **constant expression** "_ [emphasis added]. Does [expr.const#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11) have something to do here?

Comment: @std [expr.const]/11 defines what it means to be a constant expression, so yes. Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: You said, _"there is nothing to stop it from being a constant expression, since it does nothing other than calling the constexpr default constructor,"_ Where does the standard says that "when a full-expression invokes a constexpr constructor, that full-expression is a constant expression"? There's no rule in [expr.const]/11 explicitly says that. That's why I'm asking: "Does [expr.const]/11 have something to do here?"

Comment: @std Are you familiar with the fact that constant expressions are defined in terms of what they don't do? I suspect you are familiar with that list ([expr.const]/5)

Comment: @std The definition of "constant expression" in [expr.const]/11 refers to "core constant expression", and [expr.const]/5 defines a core constant expression.

Comment: I agree that the full-expression of `s` initialization is a core constant expression because it does not evaluate any of [expr.const]/5. But I don't understand why it's a constant expression. The definition of a constant expression is either a glvalue or prvalue core constant expression, but I see that the full-expression of `s`'s initialization is neither glvalue nor prvalue.

Comment: @std If your question was whether it qualifies under "glvalue core constant expression" or "prvalue core constant expression" then you should have been clear about that in the first place. When the initialization of a non-reference variable is treated as a full-expression for the purposes of determining whether it is a constant expression, it is treated as a prvalue (the standard does not explicitly say this, but it is the only reasonable reading). Similarly if the variable is of reference type, it is treated as a glvalue.

Comment: So you mean that the full expression of the initialization of `s` is "prvalue core constant expression"?

Comment: @std Yes, I think that was quite clearly implied by my last comment.

Comment: _"When the initialization of a non-reference variable is treated as a full-expression for the purposes of determining whether it is a constant expression, it is treated as a prvalue"_ Does this because the `S s{};` is treated as `S s = S{};`?

Comment: @std I'm not sure what you mean by that. The initialization is what it is. It's just that the result of the initialization (i.e. the initial value that it yields in the object being initialized) has to satisfy the constraints applicable to prvalue constant expressions, e.g., if any members are of pointer type, they can't point to an object with automatic, dynamic, or thread-local storage duration. The standard doesn't say this explicitly but it seems to be the only reasonable interpretation.

Comment: When you said _"It satisfies .. (2.2) since the **full-expression of its initialization** is a constant expression"_ [emphasis added]. What do you mean by "the full-expression of its initialization"? If this requires a separate question, I've already opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73883008/19495502) on that.