# Understand the full-expression of a constexpr variable initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following program [compiles successfully](https://godbolt.org/z/3c1xsh6oz) with all major compilers:

```
struct S {
    constexpr S(const S&){};
    constexpr S() = default;
};

int main(void) {
    S s1{};
    constexpr S s2{ s1 };
}
```

The rule governing the initialization of `constexpr` variables is [[dcl.constexpr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#10): (emphasis mine)

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have a literal type and shall be initialized. **In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression (7.7)**. A `constexpr` variable shall have constant destruction.

Per the **bold part**, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a *constant expression*. Per my understanding, the *full-expression* here is the *init-declarator* per [[into.execution]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.execution#5):

> A *full-expression* is
>
> - [..] (5.4) an init-declarator ([dcl.decl]) [..]

Per the grammar of [*init-declarator*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.decl#nt:init-declarator), the *init-declarator* is a *declarator* followed by an *initializer*:

```
init-declarator:
    declarator initializer
```

Given this information, we can conclude that the full-expression of the initialization `constexpr S s2{ s1 };` is `s2{ s1 }` where `s2` is a *declarator* and `{ s1 }` is an *initializer*.

Now, [[dcl.constexpr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#10) tells us that the full-expression (which is `s2{ s1 }` *init-declarator*) shall be a *constant expression*. And I've stucked at this point. Per [[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#11), a *constant expression* is either a glvalue or prvalue core constant expression (with some additional constraints).

For the above example, I found myself reading [[dcl.constexpr]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#10) as: "the full-expression `s2{ s1 }` shall be a glvalue or prvalue core constant expression". So how the init-declarator `s2{ s1 }` can be a glvalue or prvalue core constant expression? As you can see, my interpretation led me to a wrong theory. So, What did I misread/conflate here?

Intuitively, I just see the init-declarator `s2{ s1 }` is a copy constructor call with `s1` as an argument. But that is not the problem I'm trying to understand. Also, why the above program is well-formed is not what I'm trying to ask for. Instead, I need to know why my interpretation of this rule has not brought us to a reasonable conclusion.

---

**EDIT**

Note, the same problem we will encounter with this simple example ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T7411qW7d)):

```
int main(void) {
    static const int i = 42;
    constexpr int j = i; 
    constexpr const int &r = i;
}
```

The full-expression of the initialization `constexpr int j = i;` *is* the init-declarator `j = i`, where `j` is a *declarator* and `= i` is an *initializer* So, How can the full-expression `j = i` be a prvalue core constant expression?

The full-expression of the initialization `constexpr const int &r = i;` *is* the init-declarator `&r = i`, where `&r` is a *declarator* and `= i` is an *initializer*. So, How can the full-expression `&r = i` be a glvalue core constant expression?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248421/discussion-on-question-by-std-understand-the-full-expression-of-a-constexpr-vari).

Answer (score 1):

There's obviously a wording gap in the standard. Your understanding is correct: the standard requires the "full-expression of the initialization" of a `constexpr` variable to be a "constant expression", and the standard also states that a "constant expression" is either a "glvalue core constant expression" or a "prvalue core constant expression" (each of which must satisfy some further requirements) so it seems that the standard is telling us that the full-expression of an initialization, which is not a true expression and therefore can never be a glvalue or a prvalue (since value categories are only applicable to expressions), is neither a "glvalue core constant expression" nor a "prvalue core constant expression" and is, therefore, not a "constant expression" at all. This interpretation is obviously not intended, because it would make it impossible to have any `constexpr` variables at all.

In practice, compilers seem to take the interpretation that, solely for the purposes of [expr.const]/11:

- the initialization of a *reference* variable `r` is a glvalue designating `r`, and
- the initialization of a *non-reference* variable `o` is a prvalue that stores into its result object the value of `o`, and
- in both cases, the full-expression of the initialization includes various subexpressions that are required by the initialization, *e.g.*, the evaluation of the initializer (if any), the constructor call that initializes the variable (if any), the conversions of initializer-clauses to aggregate element types, and any implicit calls to conversion functions. It is this full-expression that needs to be checked as a core constant expression (*i.e.* we have to take it as *E* in [[expr.const]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5)).

Any other interpretation would be highly counterintuitive and lead to absurdities.

Comment: Informally, can I say that the initialization of a `constexpr` reference variable has to qualify under "glvalue core constant expression constraints", otherwise, the initialization has to qualify under "prvalue core constant expression constraints"? [ otherwise = initialization of any constexpr variable of non-reference type ]

Comment: @std If you feel that that's a good way to summarize what I said, then go ahead.

Comment: Is this mean the comment is correct?

Comment: @std It seems correct enough to me. I'm not sure why you're asking me this. I assume you understood my answer and I think you can summarize it without having to check with me.

Comment: [expr.const]/5 starts with _"An expression `E` is a core constant expression unless .."_ So what's `E` in this initialization `constexpr int j = i;`? Is it the init-declarator `j = i`?

Comment: @std More specifically it's a hypothetical expression that includes the entire init-declarator but is a prvalue.

Comment: I mean, when I enter [expr.const]/5, I need to know what's `E`. You didn't mention that in your answer even though I asks this in the OP.  For example, what's `E` in this initialization `constexpr int j = i;` Let me know if it `j = i`.

Comment: You thankfully said that the initialization `constexpr int j = i;` is prvalue designating `j`. So what next? you have to check to see if any of [expr.const]/5 constraints are evaluated here. And to know that you have to know what's `E`. I mentioned all of this in my question. So can you complete the answer at least for me?

Comment: @mada I addressed this in the third bullet. The "full-expression of the initialization" involves everything that the initialization does. That means the evaluation of the initializer, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of the initializer, and the actual bestowing of the initial value upon `i`. It is not equivalent to `j = i` (which is an assignment).